# How to check User facebook page like or not in v3.1

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have crated app on this link https://developers.facebook.com/ My app version is v3.1. I have use facebook api only scripting.
 I want to check current  user is like facebook page or not,If user is not like facebook page then request to like page,if user is liked  then content are showing.

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId:'xxx',
        xfbml: true,
        cookie: true,
        status: true,
        secret: 'xxx',
        version: 'v3.1'
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
      function (href, widget) {
          //alert('Ti piace ' + href);         
          //document.getElementById('fb-like').style.display = "none";          

          //var x = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].getAttribute("title");    
          // alert(x);         
      });

    FB.api({ method: 'pages.isFan', page_id:'xxx' }, function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
        if (resp) {
            alert('You like it.');
        } else {
            alert("You don't like it.");
        }
    });

};

(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Error are occurred like this. I am tired please help me this problems.
      erro_code:"104" erro_msg:"Incorrect signature(104),request_args:Arrar(7),error_subcode: "0"

Answer (score 2):

- Gating content behind likes is not allowed since many years.
- The `edge.create` event has been removed. It would only allow to detect new likes anyway, not existing ones.
- "pages.isFan" is very old, it would be `/me/likes` instead to get the Pages a user likes. And that only works if the user authorizes your App with the `user_likes` permission. You will not get that permission approved in the review process for like gating or incentivizing users to like your Page in any way.

**TL;DR: Not possible and not allowed.**

Comment: hello @Luschn i have no idea about this.I have found from google above this code but it is not working fine.May you send me this type of requirement code??I mean with example..

Comment: that code you found is several years old. i am not sure what code you want, it is not possible anymore and (which is even more important) not allowed.